# django - object filter logic

Tags: python, database, django

i am stuck in this state: i have locations table in db. and i also have rating table, which contains rating of each location referencing by the id of each location.

now i want to get the first 5 locations and its rating. so i have to touch 2 tables now: locations and rating.

i did this:

```
all_locations = Locations.objects.all()[:5]
all_ratings = Rating.objects.filter(of_location=all_locations.id)
```

but this seems to be wrong because `all_locations` is a queryset containing 5 locations and not one location, so it has 5 different ids. but how can i achieve this goal?: **take 5 locations and ratings of each of these 5 locations.**

Comment: Try a loop to go over those 5? Have you tried that approach??

Comment: @CppLearner, no, i didnot try this yet. you mean, i loop over 5 locations and ask for rating depending on each locations id? but then dont i overwrite ratings queryset in every step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) to indicate that the value is contained in a list:

```
locations_ids = [location.id for location in Locations.objects.all()[:5]]
all_ratings = Rating.objects.filter(location__id__in=locations_ids)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
all_locations = Locations.objects.all()[:5]
all_ratings = Rating.objects.filter(of_location__id__in=[location.id for location in all_locations])
```